# search through multiple arrays and print entire list if desired element is found

Tags: python, arrays, list

Here is my current code:

```
search=input('Enter a book title')

def read_book():
    booksdata=[]
    f=open('books2.txt', 'r')
    for record in f:
        cleanrecord=record.strip()
        books=cleanrecord.split(',')
        booksdata.append(books)
    f.close()
    return booksdata

read_book()
```

It opens up a text file that has data stored like this:

```
1, The Hunger Games, Adventure, Suzanne Collins, 1/08/2006, coai
2, Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Fantasy, J.K Rowling, 25/09/2021, ajyp
```

Im trying to program it so if the user types in 'Hunger', the entirety of the list(s) that contains hunger will get printed out:

```
['1', ' The Hunger Games', ' Adventure', ' Suzanne Collins', ' 1/08/2006', ' coai']
```

Comment: You'll need conditional statement (like `if`) to check if the word is in `books` and only append it if that's true. And you'll need a print statement or some loop printing all the books that are returned at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if your input is it in every row

```
search=input('Enter a book title')

def read_book():
    booksdata=[]
    f=open('books2.txt', 'r')
    for record in f:
        if search in record: # check
            cleanrecord=record.strip()
            books=cleanrecord.split(',')
            booksdata.append(books)
    f.close()
    return booksdata

result = read_book()
print (result)
```

output:

```
 [['1', ' The Hunger Games', ' Adventure', ' Suzanne Collins', ' 1/08/2006', ' coai']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in read_book():
    if any(['hunger' in w.lower() for w in d]):
        print(d)
```

The function `any()` takes in a list of booleans as argument and returns True if any of the value is true. The list that we are giving it stores, for every element in d, whether the string 'hunger' is present in (is a substring of) that element.